# How do I integrate eBay FindItem API into Filemaker Pro?

Tags: php, html, filemaker, ebay-api

I have followed [the tutorial](http://developer.ebay.com/Devzone/finding/HowTo/PHP_SearchInterm_NV_XML/PHP_SearchInterm_NV_XML.html) and had created the php file which shows the advanced search. It's working fine when opened in a browser and is generating query as required.

I can display the same file which is localhost/...../xyz.php in filemaker pro web viewer.

how can i make those query related section in Filemaker and integrate it so it displays results in the web viewer?

I can make fields in filemaker and also can make relationships between separate tables as per my requirement but i don't know how to integrate and link it with a webpage.

Do i have to modify the webpage in such way that i can make the query from outside, e.g.:

`"http://www.google.com/search?" & "q=" & "..."`

where in filemaker i can link the field for search as:-

`"http://www.google.com/search?" & "q=" & XMLtutorial::query`

Please help on this how to modify the PHP file in such way that i can access those query like the one on google.

Answer (score 0):

Change $_POST to $_GET or $_REQUEST and pass the fields and values as url name value pairs to your page. 
i.e.

```
"http://localhost/FindItemsAdvanced.php?Query=" & queryField & "&GlobalID=" & globalIDField
```

You also can now use FileMaker 12+'s Insert From URL script step that will get the results of your URL and put them in a field in FileMaker that you can then parse.